# Submitting a package to packagist causing "composer_home env variable" error

Tags: composer-php, packagist

Whenever I submit a git package to my packagist installation, I get the following error:

[image]

`Uncaught Exception: [RuntimeException] The HOME or COMPOSER_HOME environment variable must be set for composer to run correctly`

I've tried exporting the variable manually, but that doesn't seem to resolve the error.

Comment: Looks like a failure on the packagist.org website, doesn't it?

Comment: This is a self-hosted packagist installation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The php user didn't have HOME or COMPOSER_HOME set, so I created a php.ini file in my web root with the following contents:

`auto_prepend_file = /home/yourusername/directory/set_environment.php`

I then created a set_environment.php file in the same directory, and set my COMPOSER_HOME directory.

`<?php putenv("COMPOSER_HOME=/home/etc/webapps/novuspackagist/.composer"); ?>`

Now, whenever the app is run, the COMPOSER_HOME environment variable will be set.

Answer (score 1):

A much easier way is to add the environment variable into the apache configuration within the virtual host block, e.g.:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName myhost.home

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/packagist/web

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/packagist/web>
            AllowOverride All
            SetEnv COMPOSER_HOME /home/<user>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

As you can see the `SetEnv COMPOSER_HOME /home/<user>` directive makes it possible.
This should solve that kind of problems.